# How to read PLay! API docs?

Tags: scala, playframework

Searching for method for method `WebSocket.accept` leads to : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.WebSocket where the only method mentioned described is :

[image]

It appears the `accept` method is not a member of `WebSocket` ?

---

Searching with Google I find method defined in javadoc :

[image]

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/play/mvc/WebSocket.MappedWebSocketAcceptor.html

But this does'nt describe the Scala version.

Where is the scala doc for WebSocket.accept ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accept` is a member of the `WebSocket` object. The link you provide is to a trait. See here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.WebSocket$

Comment: thanks, should the WebSocket object not be accessible from searching the API ? Searching for WebSocket just points to the trait.

Comment: ah I should click the object icon associated with the trait to see the object implementation

Comment: Yes, it is a little tricky because only the trait icon has a label